# Suprema Biomini,How to Generate template from image

Tags: java, biometrics

Is it possible to generate the template from an image using Suprema sdk BioMini V3.7.5?

I have read the documentation but I can not find the option

[image: Documentacion]

Answer (score 1):

The function is not supported even in the current version.

UFS_Extract and UFS_ExtractEx is for the image captured by using the BioMini device.

The below is just my opinion.

> It may be hard to support the function. The resolution of the image is
>   very important factor on processing to convert from an image to a
>   template.